# Looking for OpenVZ replacement in Debian 9 - I need to test software with 1000+ virtual hosts

Tags: debian, virtual-machine

I came from the past, where OpenVZ could be used to create 1024 virtual hosts with diffrent IP addresses by using with pretty simple script written in 10 minutes.

I just realized, that OpenVZ is deprecated and I can't install it on my new server with Debian 9, because OpenVZ cannot support these new kernels with big weird version numbers.

My needs:
- 1024 virtual hosts
- 1024 IP addresses connected to my physical local network
- simple management

What options I have today for virtualization at that scale?

Comment: Do you need to test the software *with* 1000 hosts connected, or the software *on* 1000 hosts? Does the software need a different configuration in each host? 1024 network namespace with 1024 different IP addresses, which all run the same program or same set of programs (possibly with different commandline args) can be done with a simple script (`ip netns ...`) in 5 minutes. 1024 complete containers with different different root dirs is harder.

Comment: @dirkt separate /home directory (or partition) would be very helpful. Separate mysql database would be nice too, but I can worka round this and use one mysql engine with 1024 databases. Actually... Maybe I can worka round filesystem too...

Comment: Throwing in a mount namespace for 1024 /home directories won't be much more effort (unless you can make the path an argument for your software, or use the current directory. Will probably also make the software cleaner). `mysql` communicates via TCP, so just start 1024 mysql servers (with configurations for different database file paths, or the database in a mount namespace) in each network namespace. Still less complexity than a complete Docker or LXC image.

Answer (score 2):

Start looking into Linux container technologies like LXC, Docker or systemd-nspawn. They all use the same kernel facilities (namespaces), but provide different levels of abstraction and different tooling.